# Cambiar color segun status

Tags: javascript

En una tabla `X` se pueden dar de baja `status = 0` o dar de alta `status= 1`, estos cambio se reflejan en otra tabla a continuación:

```
for(var i = 0; i < activos.length; i++)
    {

                if (activos[i].status == 0) {
                //Crea fila
                var row = document.createElement('tr');

                globalCounter++;
                var cellNum = document.createElement('td');
                cellNum.innerHTML = globalCounter;
                //Crea todas las celdas
                var CellId = document.createElement('td');
                CellId.innerHTML = activos[i].cat_name+"-"+"00"+activos[i].idSub+"-"+activos[i].numFile;

                var CellOrder = document.createElement('td');
                CellOrder.innerHTML = activos[i].id_ticket;

                var CellDescription = document.createElement('td');
                CellDescription.innerHTML = activos[i].description_item;

                var CellLocation = document.createElement('td');
                CellLocation.innerHTML = activos[i].name_location;

                var CellCant = document.createElement('td');
            CellCant.innerHTML = activos[i].quantityTicket;

            var CellDate = document.createElement('td');
            CellDate.innerHTML = activos[i].registerTicket;

            var CellStatus = document.createElement('td');

                //si es inactivo = 0 se dibuja el circulo rojo en la tabla
                var status = document.createElement('i');
                status.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-circle text-danger");
                status.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
                status.setAttribute("data-placement", "top");
                status.setAttribute("data-html", "true");
                status.setAttribute("title", "Item inactivo.");
                CellStatus.appendChild(status);

        var CellAcciones = document.createElement('td');
        CellAcciones.style.textAlign = "center";
        var edit = document.createElement('button');
        var editImg = document.createElement('img');

            /*Crea toda la celda de editar*/
            var editImg = document.createElement('i');
            editImg.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-pencil");
            editImg.style.color="#000000";
            edit.appendChild(editImg);
            edit.className = 'btn btn-w-m btn-warning';
            edit.style.minWidth = '0px';
            edit.style.marginLeft="20px";
            edit.setAttribute("onclick", "editModal('" +
            activos[i].id_ticket + "', '" + activos[i].image +"', '" + activos[i].cat_name +"', '" +
            activos[i].idSub +"', '" + activos[i].numFile +"', '" + activos[i].description_item +"', '" +
            activos[i].quantityTicket +"', '" + activos[i].quantity +"', '" +
            activos[i].comentTicket +"', '" + activos[i].name_category +"','" +
            activos[i].name_sub +"','" + activos[i].name_location +"','" +
            activos[i].model_item +"','" + activos[i].price_Ticket +"','" + activos[i].name_unit +"','" +
            activos[i].company_supplier +"', '"+ activos[i].manufacturer +"','" +
            activos[i].commentt +"','" + activos[i].name_engineer +"','" + activos[i].registerTicket +"','" + activos[i].price_item +"','" + activos[i].unit_Ticket +"','" + activos[i].target_Stock +"','" + activos[i].quantity +"',)");
            edit.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
            edit.setAttribute("data-placement", "top");
            edit.setAttribute("data-html", "true");
            edit.setAttribute("title", "Click para editar informacion de entrada.");
            CellAcciones.appendChild(edit);

        //Aniade toda las celdas creadas con anteriridad a la fila
    row.appendChild(cellNum);
        row.appendChild(CellId);
        row.appendChild(CellOrder);
    row.appendChild(CellDescription);
    row.appendChild(CellLocation);
        row.appendChild(CellCant);
    row.appendChild(CellDate);
    row.appendChild(CellStatus);
    row.appendChild(CellAcciones);
        //Aniade a la tabla la fila
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

Lo que necesito es que en aquella tabla `X` cuando se da de baja un `item` en el codigo anterior ponga en la tabla un `status` con color rojo, eso lo hago con `status.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-circle text-danger");` pero cuando se vuelve a dar de alta quisiera que el color fuera verde de `activo`, pero si lo hago del lado falso de `(activos[i].status == 0)` como le hago para no volver a poner todo el código anterior es decir..

```
else 
{
   var row = document.createElement('tr');

                globalCounter++;
                var cellNum = document.createElement('td');
                cellNum.innerHTML = globalCounter;
                //Crea todas las celdas
                var CellId = document.createElement('td');
                CellId.innerHTML = activos[i].cat_name+"-"+"00"+activos[i].idSub+"-"+activos[i].numFile;
......
}
```

Este seria el codigo para poner el color a verde.

```
            var status = document.createElement('i');
            status.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-circle text-navy");
            status.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
            status.setAttribute("data-placement", "top");
            status.setAttribute("data-html", "true");
            status.setAttribute("title", "item activo.");
```

Comment: Lo único que cambia entre el estado 1 y estado 0 es el atributo `title`?

Comment: title y class, eso solo dibuja un punto verde o rojo segun sea el caso, desde un principio comparo si el status es = 0 entonces en la tabla X al dar de baja algun item en esta tabla me pone el punto rojo de inactivo, cuando en la tabla X cambio el status a activo me debe poner el punto verde, pero no se como ponerlo sin repetir de nuevo todo como lo puse al inicio pero del lado falso de status =0

Answer (score 0):

Tenes dos opciones sencillas para solucionar tu problema, uno es el uso de una función, por ejemplo:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('ejemplo');

cambiarEstilo(0);

//Defino una función que recibe un parámetro
function cambiarEstilo(activo)
{   
  //Utilizando un condicional, chequeo el parámetro, y según sea el caso..
  if(activo==1)
  //Agrego la clase activo
  elem.setAttribute('class','activo');  
  else
  //Agrego la clase inactivo
  elem.setAttribute('class','inactivo');
}
```

```css
.activo { color:green; }
.inactivo { color:red; }
```

```html
<p id="ejemplo">I'm blue</p>
```

---

Otra opción sería la de usar el [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) que creo que en tu caso va a ser más aplicable

Para aplicarlo se hace de la siguiente manera

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('ejemplo');
var estado = 1;

//En caso de que estado valga 1, la clase activo se agregará, caso contrario, la clase inactivo
elem.setAttribute('class', estado==1 ? 'activo' : 'inactivo');
```

```css
.activo { color:green; }
.inactivo { color:red; }
```

```html
<p id="ejemplo">Soy un ejemplo</p>
```